# How can I define PDO in SLIM Framework so that PhpStorm doesn't throw 'method not found in class' warnings?

Tags: php, pdo, phpstorm, slim

So I stick PDO into my SLIM using this:

```
$container['dbh'] = function($container) {
    $config = $container->get('settings')['pdo'];
    $dsn = "{$config['engine']}:host={$config['host']};dbname={$config['database']};charset={$config['charset']}";
    $username = $config['username'];
    $password = $config['password'];

    return new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $config['options']);
};
```

However, every time I use `$this->dbh->execute()` (or some other PDO method), PhpStorm warns me `method 'execute' not found in class`

Realistically it doesn't make a difference but I'd like my PhpStorm to stop warning me about things that it doesn't need to.

Comment: In your class docblock, you could add `@property $dbh PDO` (might need to be the other way around, not sure)

Comment: Advanced Metadata? https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/PhpStorm+Advanced+Metadata

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is mostly an answer adding to @rickdenhaan's comment.

I noticed that you're using `$this`, which implies you have a class somewhere.

You can typehint dynamic/fake properties in a class like so:

```
/**
 * @property PDO $dbh
 */
class MyApp {
}
```

For more help, read the PHPDoc documentation, eg [here](https://phpdoc.org/docs/latest/references/phpdoc/tags/property.html).

---

In some situations, you might not be able to influence the original class being instantiated. In that case, you can have a stub file; basically a class used only for type hinting:

```
// Let's assume you cannot modify this class.
class App {}

// This is the stub class, we declare it as abstract to avoid instantiation by mistake.
// We make it extend `App` to get metadata from there.
abstract class AppStub extends App {
    /** @var PDO */
    public $dbh;
}


// ...later on in your code..
/** @var AppStub $this */

// tada!
$this->dbh->execute();
```

---

**Controller classes approach**

Your main app + routing:

```
$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->get('/', \YourController::class . ':home');
$app->get('/contact', \YourController::class . ':contact');
```

And your controller:

```
class YourController 
{
   protected $container;

   // constructor receives container instance
   public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
       $this->container = $container;
   }

   public function home($request, $response, $args) {
        $this->getDb()->execute();   // no IDE errors anymore!
        return $response;
   }

   public function contact($request, $response, $args) {
        return $response;
   }

   /**
    * @return PDO
    */
   protected function getDb()
   {
       return $this->container->get('dbh');
   }
}
```

Comment: Well, the class is Slim Framework, installed from Composer. How could I add such a typehint in a way that will persist through VCS (since the framework (and related files) isn't stored in VCS)

Comment: @Christian Nice :) But isn't it little bit exaggerated? ;)

Comment: Ah this is great! Not a big deal but: for Slim I have to add something like this `$app->get('/Route, function(Request $request, Response $response) {` for every Route I want. Is there a way around adding `/** @var AppStub $this */` to each Route? Can I somehow put it in the stub?

Comment: @arbogast depends on how large the project is. Larger projects could even make use of autogenerated stubs (for example, we use this to get auto-completion in PHPStorm for Symfony DIC).

Comment: @Rob one way of doing it is to make use of [controller classes and route to them](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#allow-slim-to-instantiate-the-controller) instead of using callbacks. This has the added advantage that you won't need the stub class anymore. I've updated the answer with an example. Careful: it's untested code.

Answer (score 1):

If your class is in a namespace, you should use `\PDO` to indicate that you are referring to a class in the root namespace.

Answer (score 0):

If PhpStorm has problems with identifying variable/object, so for example it has warning 'Method some_method not found in...' for example for code like:

```
$my_object->some_method();
```

then you can help PhpStorm to identify class by adding variable type definition in comment like this:

```
/**
 * @var \Some\Class $my_object
 */
$my_object->some_method();
```

General example. Add this comment before using $my_object variable (for example at the beggining of method were you will use variable $my_object, or before first usage of this variable):

```
/**
 * @var \Some\Class $my_object
 */
```

and now every time you will use this variable in method, PhpStorm will know that this variable is an instance of \Some\Class, so warnings will disappear in following lines, for every usage of this variable. For example warnings will not show for this kind of usage:

```
/**
 * @var \Some\Class $my_object
 */
...
$my_object->some_method();
... 
$my_object->some_method1();
...
$my_object->some_method2();
...
$my_object->some_method();
```

Comment: Do I need to add this every time I call the method?

Comment: @Rob You must add this once per assigning object to variable. So after adding this comment PhpStorm knows that variable $my_object is an instance of \Some\Class. I will edit my answer to show you example.

Comment: @Rob - if you use `$my_object` in a different scope then you also need to typehint it (as suggested above). That said, I do not think this answer will be helpful to you since you're dealing with properties, not variables.